# how to send the ajax array values to php and how to check script value is assigned or not

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send the array value to php using array

```
<script>
$('input.update').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
});

function sendvalue() {
  // Array
  var postData = [];
  $('input.update').each(function() {
     var inp = $(this);
     postData.push({
        previous: inp.data('val'),
        currentvalue: inp.val(),
     });

});
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateedit.php",
    data:postData, 

    success: function(data)  {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('failed');
    }               
  });

}
</script>
```

My php page

```
foreach($_POST['postData] as $value)
{
  echo $value;
}
```

In My php page I got the Error as undefined index:postData and how to check if the script value is assigned or not

Answer (score 0):

The `data` option needs to be an object. The property names of the object become the `$_POST` keys.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateedit.php",
    data: { postData: postData },
    ...
});
```